# Ninject binding generic interface to generic concrete class with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

This is strange, I'm using Ninject for dependency injection and I had no problem in binding until I bound a generic interface to a generic concrete class which is shown below:

```
// * Two below bindings are like many other bindings that are OK
Bind<ISupplierAssessmentMarkBiz>()
    .To<SupplierAssessmentMarkBiz>().InRequestScope();
Bind<ISupplierAssessmentDetailBiz>()
    .To<SupplierAssessmentDetailBiz>().InRequestScope();
// * This below binding is problematic
Bind(typeof(IHierarchyEntityBiz<KnowledgeDTO>))
    .To(typeof(HierarchyEntityBiz<Knowledge, KnowledgeDTO>)).InRequestScope();
```

Then in my controller's constructor I have this:

```
public KnowledgeController(AuthenticationService authSvc, IKnowledgeBiz knowledgeBiz,
    IHierarchyEntityBiz<KnowledgeDTO> knowledgeHierarchyBiz)
        : base(authSvc)
    {
        _knowledgeBiz = knowledgeBiz;
        _knowldegHierarchyBiz = knowledgeHierarchyBiz;
    }
```

So when I try to call a web api service, I get this error:

```
'...KnowledgeController' does not have a default constructor.
```

And in output window:

```
'A first chance exception of type 'Ninject.ActivationException' occurred in Ninject.dll'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's Ninject that is trying to create KnowledgeController? Check the call stack.

Comment: As @BatteryBackupUnit mentions below please include the entire message of the exception, including the activation stack.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing

```
Bind(typeof(IHierarchyEntityBiz<KnowledgeDTO>))
.To(typeof(HierarchyEntityBiz<Knowledge, KnowledgeDTO>)).InRequestScope();
```

with

```
Bind<IHierarchyEntityBiz<KnowledgeDTO>>()
.To<HierarchyEntityBiz<Knowledge, KnowledgeDTO>>().InRequestScope();
```

should not change anything but it might be worth a try ;-) If it doesn't help, it's at least a little bit shorter.

So for your issue.
Please give us the entire message of the exception. It should contain the activation stack, so we can see why ninject tried to instanciate a `KnowledgeController`.

Most likely you are missing bindings for `AuthenticationService` or `IKnowledgeBiz`.

Comment: Thanks, if I remove `IHierarchyEntityBiz<KnowledgeDTO> knowledgeHierarchyBiz` from constructor, the dependencies will be resolved properly and the controller works. About call stack, I don't have it, because the debugger won't even start debugging. the only thing I see is the output window which says: `"A first chance exception of type 'Ninject.ActivationException' occurred in Ninject.dll"`.

Comment: Then you should configure your debugger to break on that kind of exception. Or write some try and catch for that exception and access the exception there (or log the message). If you're in control of the source code you can get to the exception.

Comment: Did you try to modify the binding to the one i suggested?

Comment: The thing is the exception occurs in asp.net mvc source code or ninject source code (I think) and I don't know where to break the debugger. Yes I modified the binding, still the same, no change..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358406/global-error-handling-outside-of-controller-in-asp-net-mvc and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/731913/Exception-Handling-in-MVC